# Analyzing 2nd derivatives of complex functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

In one variable calculus, if the derivative was not zero, it was either positive
or negative and this led to increasing versus decreasing functions locally.
Does this extend to complex functions and if so does this mean that there's a second derivative test for complex functions?

My intuition for this problem is that this property would extend to complex functions because we are able to find the second derivative of a complex function. The difference for complex functions is we would need to analyze the idea of "increasing" and "decreasing" in the context of multivariable calculus where we would need to find the Jacobian and apply the 2nd derivative test through that method. Is this intuition correct?

Comment: The complex numbers are not ordered.  "Increasing" and "decreasing" mean nothing in this context.  The short answer is "No."

Comment: Though we don't have the notion of increasing and decreasing for complex differentiable functions, not all is lost: Suppose $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is differentiable at $z$. Then $f'(z)$ is some complex number (so we can't say "$f'(z)\geq 0$" or "$f'(z)\leq 0$" in general), but it is still useful to consider the *magnitude* of the derivative, $|f'(z)|$, which is a non-negative real number loosely representing the "steepness of $f$ at $z$."